# Activation energy of chlorine trifluoride and hydrazine

Tags: kinetics

Chlorine trifluoride was once tested in a rocket engine as an oxidizer for hydrazine. I am looking to simulate in software a rocket engine using this propellent combination. Activation energy is one of the inputs to the simulation software.

What is the activation energy of a chlorine trifluoride and hydrazine reaction?

$\ce{3 N2H4 + 4 ClF3 -> 3 N2 + 12 HF + 2Cl2}$

Is there a online chemistry source or book which might contain this value? If it has not been measured is there a way to calculate this value based on the properties of the chemicals involved? How to get the value is less important than a number I can enter into a text file.

Searching for papers on the subject mostly results in unrelated chemistry homework examples. The closest thing thing I found to an answer was looking up chemicals in the [National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) Chemical Reactions Database](http://kinetics.nist.gov/kinetics/index.jsp). The database includes data for hydrazine reactions and chlorine trifluoride reactions separately, but not with each other.

$\ce{ClF3 -> *F + ClF2}$ reaction has $E_a = 118 \frac{kJ}{mol}$. Is it reasonable to assume this might be the first step if it is a radical reaction?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. This appears to be a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question, please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution, otherwise it might get closed.

Comment: Do you really think someone was crazy enough to _measure_ this?

Comment: In case it is a high order/concerted reaction the most realistic way to get it is from the literature. In case it is not it could be a radical reaction then the rate determining step most likely is a homolytic Cl-F cleavage. That one might be calculated with some effort to even realistic accuracy.

Comment: Chlorine trifluoride is potentially the most dangerous substance ever. Please do not use it at home, or without EXTREME safety, especially when simulating a rocket engine. See the chemical spill many years ago, where 50 tons of this substance was dropped, and ate through more than a meter of concrete.

Comment: @Equinox And on that note, nor is hydrazine any good.