# Literature value for the activation energy of the reaction between hydrochloric acid and sodium bicarbonate

Tags: kinetics, energy, reference-request

Does anybody have the literature value for the activation energy of the reaction between hydrochloric acid and sodium bicarbonate? If yes, could you please cite the source for it and the value?

I searched through the internet for hours, but the closest I could find was the activation energy between sodium carbonate and HCl, nothing for bicarbonate. I tried the NIST database and could not find anything, and other databases too.

Comment: @andselisk How is this a homework question? I think it needs a separate classification

Comment: @StackUpPhysics I would even say that this is a canonical homework question as it completely lacks research attempt and asks for the data on *specific* reaction, which would be of questionable help for other users. This could also be closed as a narrowed-down duplicate of [Is there a database on chemical reactions, similar to NIST, but far more complete?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/55937). For a decent example of how a similar question could be asked, check out [Activation energy of chlorine trifluoride and hydrazine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/75996).

Comment: @andselisk Got it

Comment: I thought homework questions were allowed. I searched through the internet for hours but the closest I could find was the activation energy between sodium carbonate and HCl, nothing for bicarbonate. I tried the NIST database and could not find anything, and other databases too. What makes the question not allowed? Also, if you have an answer I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: @IoanaRaducanu If you had a closer look at the [link in the closing reason](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange), you find out that homework questions are allowed all right, it's just that you need to demonstrate your thoughts and attempt to solve the problem on your own. I appended part of your last comment to the question and re-opened it. It appears that this question resulted in a [Meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4602), so I keep all the comments JIC.

Comment: @Ioana Raducanu It is rather reaction of H3O+ and HCO3-.